# json parsing gives error

Tags: json, parsing

```
{
    "Restricted_parameters":
    {
        "abcd"
        "efgh"
        "ijkl"
        "mnop"
   }
}
```

I am new about json files and parsing it and in my current college project when I am rying to parse the json file it is giving error

Can anyone please let me know how to parse above json file

I am using JSON parser APIs also

```
Jason_parser_edf::Jason_parser_edf()
{
    Json_parser file_parser;
    // Create empty property tree object
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    uint32_t nb = 0;
    std::string //    const std::string restricted_parameters = "Restricted_parameters";
    file_parser.open_json_file(current_file_path, &pt);
    ptree::const_iterator end = pt.end();
    for (ptree::const_iterator it = pt.begin(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        BOOST_FOREACH( ptree::value_type const& v, pt.get_child(it->first) ) // parasoft-suppress MISRA2008-6_4_1 "BOOST library" // parasoft-suppress NAMING-33 "BOOST library" // parasoft-suppress BD-PB-CC "BOOST library" // parasoft-suppress MISRA2008-6_3_1 "BOOST library"
        {
            // Getting additional fields
            std::string additional_field_name = v.second.get<std::string>("Restricted_parameters");
            cout << additional_field_name << endl;
        }
    }
    // second way I am trying
    for (auto & array_element: pt) {
            for (auto & property: array_element.second) {
                std::cout << property.first << endl;
            }
        }
//    db_conf_structure.dump();
}
```

Comment: Share what you have tried.

Comment: Your json is not valid. after "abcd" must be a comma and same after "efgh" and "ijkl"

Comment: ok even if I try with placing comma then also it is giving error @Jens

Comment: Looks like `"Restricted_parameters":` is an Array, so the strings must be surrounded with [] not {}

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid format of JSON, you must remember always to have pair key: value

```
{
"Restricted_parameters":
 {
    "abcd": "val1",
    "efgh": "val2",
    "ijkl": "val3",
    "mnop": "val4"
 }
}
```

or use array

```
{
"Restricted_parameters":
 [
    "abcd",
    "efgh",
    "ijkl",
    "mnop"
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is invalid. An array is initialized through square brackets and you need commas between the items.

```
{
    "Restricted_parameters":
    [
        "abcd",
        "efgh",
        "ijkl",
        "mnop"
   ]
}
```